# Java AES encryption and decryption

Tags: java, aes, encryption

I would like to encrypt and decrypt a password using 128 bit AES encryption with 16 byte key.  I am getting `javax.crypto.BadPaddingException` error while decrypting the value.  Am I missing anything while decrypting?

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Test t = new Test();
    String encrypt = new String(t.encrypt("mypassword"));
    System.out.println("decrypted value:" + t.decrypt("ThisIsASecretKey", encrypt));
}

public String encrypt(String value) {
    try {
        byte[] raw = new byte[]{'T', 'h', 'i', 's', 'I', 's', 'A', 'S', 'e', 'c', 'r', 'e', 't', 'K', 'e', 'y'};
        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
        byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(value.getBytes());
        System.out.println("encrypted string:" + (new String(encrypted)));
        return new String(skeySpec.getEncoded());
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (BadPaddingException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InvalidKeyException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return null;
}

public String decrypt(String key, String encrypted) {
    try {
        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec(skeySpec.getEncoded(), "AES"));
        //getting error here
        byte[] original = cipher.doFinal(encrypted.getBytes());
        return new String(original);
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (BadPaddingException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InvalidKeyException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Error message

```
encrypted string:�Bj�.�Ntk�F�`�
encrypted key:ThisIsASecretKey
decrypted value:null
May 25, 2012 12:54:02 PM bean.Test decrypt
SEVERE: null
javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded
at com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE_f.b(DashoA13*..)
at com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE_f.b(DashoA13*..)
at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineDoFinal(DashoA13*..)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(DashoA13*..)
at bean.Test.decrypt(Test.java:55)
at bean.Test.main(Test.java:24)
```

**Finally I am using following Solution based on @QuantumMechanic answer**

```
public class Test {

  public String encryptionKey;

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    Test t = new Test();
    String encrypt = t.encrypt("mypassword");
    System.out.println("decrypted value:" + t.decrypt(t.encryptionKey, encrypt));
  }

  public String encrypt(String value) {
    try {
        // Get the KeyGenerator
        KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
        kgen.init(256);
        // Generate the secret key specs.
        SecretKey skey = kgen.generateKey();
        byte[] raw = skey.getEncoded();
        String key = new Base64().encodeAsString(raw);
        this.encryptionKey = key;
        System.out.println("------------------Key------------------");
        System.out.println(key);
        System.out.println("--------------End of Key---------------");
        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
        String encrypt = (new Base64()).encodeAsString(cipher.doFinal(value.getBytes()));
        System.out.println("encrypted string:" + encrypt);
        return encrypt;
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (BadPaddingException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InvalidKeyException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return null;
  }

  public String decrypt(String key, String encrypted) {
    try {
        Key k = new SecretKeySpec(Base64.getDecoder().decode(key), "AES");
        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, k);
        byte[] decodedValue = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encrypted);
        byte[] decValue = c.doFinal(decodedValue);
        String decryptedValue = new String(decValue);
        return decryptedValue;
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (BadPaddingException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InvalidKeyException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If for a block cipher you're not going to use a `Cipher` transformation that includes a padding scheme, you need to have the number of bytes in the plaintext be an integral multiple of the block size of the cipher.

So either pad out your plaintext to a multiple of 16 bytes (which is the AES block size), or specify a padding scheme when you create your `Cipher` objects.  For example, you could use:

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
```

Unless you have a good reason not to, use a padding scheme that's already part of the JCE implementation.  They've thought out a number of subtleties and corner cases you'll have to realize and deal with on your own otherwise.

---

Ok, your second problem is that you are using `String` to hold the ciphertext.

In general,

```
String s = new String(someBytes);
byte[] retrievedBytes = s.getBytes();
```

will **not** have `someBytes` and `retrievedBytes` being identical.

If you want/have to hold the ciphertext in a `String`, base64-encode the ciphertext bytes first and construct the `String` from the base64-encoded bytes.  Then when you decrypt you'll `getBytes()` to get the base64-encoded bytes out of the `String`, then base64-decode them to get the real ciphertext, then decrypt that.

The reason for this problem is that most (all?) character encodings are not capable of mapping arbitrary bytes to valid characters.  So when you create your `String` from the ciphertext, the `String` constructor (which applies a character encoding to turn the bytes into characters) essentially has to throw away some of the bytes because it can make no sense of them.  Thus, when you get bytes out of the string, they are not the same bytes you put into the string.

In Java (and in modern programming in general), you cannot assume that one character = one byte, unless you know absolutely you're dealing with ASCII.  This is why you need to use base64 (or something like it) if you want to build strings from arbitrary bytes.

Comment: Block cipher encryption algorithms require the data (mypassword in your case) to be multiple of `n` bytes, where `n` depends on the key size. Look at [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation#Padding) wiki section for more info.

Comment: I have changed the cleartext data from `mypassword` to `1234567890123456` but I still get the same exception.  My key is 16B as well

Comment: Perfect, `BASE64Encoder` and `BASE64Decoder` did the job.  Thanks

Comment: @Praneeth how did you solved? Where did you use BASE64 encoder or decoder?

Answer (score 5):

```
import javax.crypto.*;    
import java.security.*;  
public class Java {

private static SecretKey key = null;         
   private static Cipher cipher = null; 

   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
   {

      Security.addProvider(new com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE());

      KeyGenerator keyGenerator =
         KeyGenerator.getInstance("DESede");
      keyGenerator.init(168);
      SecretKey secretKey = keyGenerator.generateKey();
      cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede");

      String clearText = "I am an Employee";
      byte[] clearTextBytes = clearText.getBytes("UTF8");

      cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
      byte[] cipherBytes = cipher.doFinal(clearTextBytes);
      String cipherText = new String(cipherBytes, "UTF8");

      cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
      byte[] decryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(cipherBytes);
      String decryptedText = new String(decryptedBytes, "UTF8");

      System.out.println("Before encryption: " + clearText);
      System.out.println("After encryption: " + cipherText);
      System.out.println("After decryption: " + decryptedText);
   }
}


// Output

/*
Before encryption: I am an Employee  
After encryption: }?ｽ?ｽj6?ｽm?ｽZyc?ｽ?ｽ*?ｽ?ｽl#l?ｽdV  
After decryption: I am an Employee  
*/
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is the implementation that was mentioned above:

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.StringUtils;

try
{
    String passEncrypt = "my password";
    byte[] saltEncrypt = "choose a better salt".getBytes();
    int iterationsEncrypt = 10000;
    SecretKeyFactory factoryKeyEncrypt = SecretKeyFactory
            .getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
    SecretKey tmp = factoryKeyEncrypt.generateSecret(new PBEKeySpec(
            passEncrypt.toCharArray(), saltEncrypt, iterationsEncrypt,
            128));
    SecretKeySpec encryptKey = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(),
            "AES");

    Cipher aesCipherEncrypt = Cipher
            .getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
    aesCipherEncrypt.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, encryptKey);

    // get the bytes
    byte[] bytes = StringUtils.getBytesUtf8(toEncodeEncryptString);

    // encrypt the bytes
    byte[] encryptBytes = aesCipherEncrypt.doFinal(bytes);

    // encode 64 the encrypted bytes
    String encoded = Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(encryptBytes);

    System.out.println("e: " + encoded);

    // assume some transport happens here

    // create a new string, to make sure we are not pointing to the same
    // string as the one above
    String encodedEncrypted = new String(encoded);

    //we recreate the same salt/encrypt as if its a separate system
    String passDecrypt = "my password";
    byte[] saltDecrypt = "choose a better salt".getBytes();
    int iterationsDecrypt = 10000;
    SecretKeyFactory factoryKeyDecrypt = SecretKeyFactory
            .getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
    SecretKey tmp2 = factoryKeyDecrypt.generateSecret(new PBEKeySpec(passDecrypt
            .toCharArray(), saltDecrypt, iterationsDecrypt, 128));
    SecretKeySpec decryptKey = new SecretKeySpec(tmp2.getEncoded(), "AES");

    Cipher aesCipherDecrypt = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
            aesCipherDecrypt.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, decryptKey);

    //basically we reverse the process we did earlier

    // get the bytes from encodedEncrypted string
    byte[] e64bytes = StringUtils.getBytesUtf8(encodedEncrypted);

    // decode 64, now the bytes should be encrypted
    byte[] eBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(e64bytes);

    // decrypt the bytes
    byte[] cipherDecode = aesCipherDecrypt.doFinal(eBytes);

    // to string
    String decoded = StringUtils.newStringUtf8(cipherDecode);

    System.out.println("d: " + decoded);

}
catch (Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this, a simpler solution.

```
byte[] salt = "ThisIsASecretKey".getBytes();
Key key = new SecretKeySpec(salt, 0, 16, "AES");

Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
```

Comment: Oh, Make sure your key is 16 chars long.

Comment: Key is 16B `ThisIsASecretKey`

Answer (score 1):

You state that you want to encrypt/decrypt a password.  I'm not sure exactly of what your specific use case is but, generally, passwords are not stored in a form where they can be decrypted.  General practice is to salt the password and use suitably powerful one-way hash (such as PBKDF2).

Take a look at the following link for more information.

http://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm

Answer (score 0):

Complete example of *encrypting/Decrypting* a **huge video without throwing Java** `OutOfMemoryException` and using Java `SecureRandom` for Initialization Vector generation. Also depicted storing key bytes to database and then reconstructing same key from those bytes.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18892960/185022