# AES encryption base64().encodetoString unidentified by java netbean

Tags: java, base64, aes

I am currently working on an AES encryption 256 bit function found here:

http://deveshsharma.info/2012/10/09/256-bit-aes-password-based-encryption-in-java

What I am trying to do now is to see the output of the code above. But NetBean can't read `encodeAsString` after I import it.

```
import com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dv.util.Base64;
...
byte[] encryptedTextBytes = cipher.doFinal(plainText.getBytes("UTF-8"));
return new     Base64().encodeAsString(encryptedTextBytes);
```

When I check with (alt+enter on encodeAsString), the error is

> "cannot find symbol .. Base64 is internal proprietary API and may be
>   removed in a future release"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64 instead of the obsolete sun import for Base64.  See also [Java AES encryption and decryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10759392/java-aes-encryption-and-decryption) (and no I'm not the one who voted the question down)

Answer (score 2):

Folk i realize i did not have the right jar for the base64.
for folk who have the same problem as me please download commons-codec-1.9-bin.zip at http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/download_codec.cgi to able run the given code.

Answer (score 2):

Java 8 has a Base64 encode in package **java.util.Base64**.  It is actually one of the better performers: [performance comparisons of various encoders for the java platform](http://java-performance.info/base64-encoding-and-decoding-performance/)

try not to use the implementation under the sun packages: e.g. com.sun.org.apache.xerces.... they are not supported and much slower.