# How to set encrypted password to credentials to publish Nexus OSS with sbt?

Tags: scala, sbt, nexus

I'm trying to access a Nexus OSS repository with unencrypted password in `global.sbt` like [this](https://github.com/xerial/sbt-sonatype#homesbtsbt-versionsonatypesbt), my `global.sbt` is:

```
 credentials += Credentials("Sonatype Nexus", "repo.example.com", "username", "unencrypted_password")
```

I'd like to thinking about setting encrypted password.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a file called `.credentials`, under `~/.ivy2/.credentials`. That's a fairly standard location, but obviously you can place your file anywhere on disk.

The file looks like this:

```
realm = Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager
host = oss.sonatype.org
user = publishing@yourco.com
password = $encrypted
```

To encrypt the password, you can use a known AES cypher, which means you can basically do something like this:

```
val credential: DirectCredentials = Credentials(Path.userHome / ".ivy2" / ".credentials")
val decrypted = credential.copy(passwd = decryptAes(credential.passwd))
```

Now what you need is a shared cypher company wide or similar, as well as a method to decrypt AES, and for that look [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10759392/java-aes-encryption-and-decryption).