# How can I encrypt a video stream

Tags: java, video, encryption, stream, cypher

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Encryption of video files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9496447/encryption-of-video-files)

I want to encrypt a video stream using stream cypher and send it to a client PC where the client PC can play it on the fly.

Question: What types of stream cypher I can use for this purpose?

I am using java for coding.

Answer (score 1):

Tunnel the stream over SSL.

If you are using some form of HTTP streaming (such as HLS), then it should be trivial to make that HTTPs.