# how to secure videos in SDCard (android)

Tags: java, android, security, android-sdcard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Encryption of video files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9496447/encryption-of-video-files)

i starting new project that needs to have lot of videos storing in the sdcard but i don't want users can access this videos or share it because this is paid app 
i read about des encryption for Strings 
can i make encryption for videos? and please can you give me hint or tutorial about this subject

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/9496447/1720391 as pointed out by Goo.  However, that does not suggest a method for playing the video without exposing it in decrypted form, which is the more challenging part of the problem.  Also, decryption keys can be extracted from the application unless substantial effort is made to obfuscate them.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can encrypt any file with `CipherInputStream` and `CipherOutputStreamin`

You can find an example of theses cipher methods in this post : [Encryption of video files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9496447/1720391)