# How to hide the selected images from the gallery from my application

Tags: android

What is the better approach of hiding selected images from the gallery from my application.

1. Changing the extension of the image with some extension

   **Problem with appraoch 1**: Using file explorer we can view the images
2. Encryption of images
3. Storing the images in our local database and deleting the image from the location

Please can any one suggest the best appraoch

Answer (score 1):

**1. Chnaging Extention:** This is not a good way to do.

**2. Encryption of Image:** If it is a security reason this is a better ontion but if anyone delete that file then you may face problem.

**3. Storing the images in our local database and deleting the image from the location:** This is also a good option.

I will suggest you to go with option 3 i.e. **Storing the images in our local database and deleting the image from the location.**

Comment: When dealing with videos..what would be the better solution

Comment: if it is video then go for Encryption. You can Encrypt video. To encrypt video use this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9496447/encryption-of-video-files