# Offline viewing of videos in android app

Tags: android, cordova

I am about to start an android app which includes categorizing different videos and streaming it from device, this app needs a feature as 'offline viewing' which enables the user to download the video and store it in the device for offline viewing(user cannot copy the videos and move it to somewhere else and watch ),

I was searching and found that so many apps are using this feature 
like
[pluralsight](http://www.pluralsight.com/training/products/offlineviewing),  [Lynda](http://www.lynda.com/support/faq.aspx?category=191&faq=3966) and many more

How can I accomplish this feature in my own android app? are the videos encrypted and stored? Any advises will be so helpful for me as I am stuck at this point.

Thanks

Comment: rough idea: you can download the video in a more safe folder. something like storage->sdcard->application->data->com.yourcom.yourapp->yourvideo. This way though there is a change that someone might found the video but general users don't go in these folders to check.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9496447/encryption-of-video-files

Comment: @AtanuCSE Thanks for the link and the Idea, I'll definitely try that CipherInputStream  out..

Comment: Place videos in internal/external file system and access it. Example:-- <video controls='controls'>
 <source src= "file:/storage/sdcard0/video_name.mp4" type='video/mp4'>;
</video>