# Video Encryption in android

Tags: android, video, encryption

i am working on an application like you tube in which i want to implement offline feature. Please suggest where i save the video file so that user can not access it outside from the application.

I had already did some R&D on this part and found that we can save the video in application private storage but i think only limited amount of data we can save in application private storage , so this approach is not beneficial in my case.

Then please suggest how can i achieve this in android ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think from your description that you probably want to use DRM - this will not 'hide' where the video is stored but it will encrypt the video so that only someone with the right key can watch it.

There are a number of widely available DRM schemes - Widevine modular is one example that will support the offline behaviour you are looking for.

If you don't feel you need the features of a full DRM implementation you could just encrypt the video yourself and build a simpler mechanism to get the key to a valid user (this is essentially what DRM systems do, albeit with more techniques and tricks to keep the key safely secret)>

Comment: that means i need to encrypt the file . am i right ? can you give me some example for it ?

Comment: You can either do it yourself (see example here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9496626/334402) or use a third party DRM service (just google DRM service).