# how to save video in encrypted format from url to storage in android

Tags: java, android

I want to implement feature like youtube offline video.
I have to store the video from url in encrypted form in local storage and decrypt that video when user plays offline video

Comment: What do you exactly mean in encrypted format?

Comment: what exactly is a problem? You can't download video? You can't encrypt it? You can't decrypt it?

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko I have to save that video in encrypted form. How to exactly encrypt the video so that user cannot find .mp4 file in storage like youtube saves offline videos

Comment: @alexandrius encrypted means that user could not find that video file in storage. it must be saved in .exo format or any other user unreadable format

Comment: Video is a file. You basically need to encrypt a file. Just search for how to encrypt a file

Comment: see - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9496447/encryption-of-video-files

Comment: See this link https://www.lifewire.com/exo-file-2621155