# saved internal memory video should not be Share to another Application

Tags: android, video, download

I am working on an android application in that included premium account video I downloading with single and multiple on a time but I need to Implement that downloaded video should not be sharable to any other application please give me suggestion I would appreciate every response Thank you in advance

Comment: as a security purpose how to keep it without share with any other application

Comment: Download the video to getFilesDIr() of your app and you are done.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to make use of Encrypting video instead of breaking your head in trying to hide. As you are aware there are multiple ways to find out the video even if it stored in folder with .(dot)(foldername)

Please find the link given below which talks about encrypting and decryption of videos
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18892960/2850044